# Does engineering modules increase their value?

Tags: elite-dangerous

If you engineer a module and then decide to sell it or upgrade it will it be worth more than its stock value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

While engineering modules has an impact on their performance, selling these modules will net you the same value an unengineered module would provide at the given station.